# Circular working out with partial derivatives

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, chain-rule

My question is the related to the example below:

> Why don't we use chain rule when differentiating this:

**Example:** Suppose $x,y$ are functions of $u,v$ and $z = x^2+y$, where

\begin{cases} x=e^u \cos(v) \\ y=e^u \sin(v) \end{cases}

**Required to find:** $$ \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} $$

If I'm differentiating $z=x^2+y$ with respect to $ x $, my first impulse would be to say

$$ \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = 2x$$

But when I think about it, I don't understand why we don't use chain rule (when differentiating y) again because $ y $ and $x $ are related so isn't $y$ also a function of $ x$. $$ y = x \tan(v) $$

So why isn't the answer as below?:
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = 2x+ \frac{dy}{dx} = 2x+\tan(v) $$

Can someone please clarify for me when chain rule is required and when it is not and please **explain what is wrong with the logic/reasoning above**. Thanks!

Comment: Here $y$ is treated as constant when the derivative is taken with respect to $x.$

Comment: I think you mean $\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x} = 2x$ ("my first impulse would be to say…"). Or do you indeed mean $\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x} = y$. That would be a weird conclusion, even if you thought $y$ depended on $x$ (for that would imply $y = ke^x$).

Comment: Yes I did, apologies edited

Comment: @Sean Robertson but this would not be the case if $y$ was explicitly a function of $x$, which would require chain rule. Isn't It possible to write it this way by eliminating the parameters?

Comment: You would use the chain rule if you wanted to calculate $\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}$ or $\frac{\partial z}{\partial v}$.

Comment: Yes I agree with that but I don't understand why this wouldn't apply in this example, doesn't $y=x\tan v $ imply $ y =f(x,v) $

Comment: Closely related to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3151114/265466, if not a duplicate of it.

Comment: I read the verified answer to this post, but I wasn't quite convinced. What if there were no specified variable that was constant, what would you assume? (According to convention)